# how to stretch a string both horizontally and vertically in haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to stretch a string in haskell both horizontally and vertically by the given input of two int values. I have the correct code, just don't know how to implement it correctly:

```
 expansion :: Int -> Int -> String -> String
 expansion extendTo e n m a = setSize e (max n $ nrows a) (max m $ ncols a) a
```

in the book it states scale the input picture by the integer provided as the first and second argument. For instance if exPic is the picture:

```
#.#
..#
```

then the result of expansion exPic 2 2 should be:

```
##..##
##..##
....##
....##
```

The book I'm using gives no solutions otherwise i wouldn't have to ask!!

Comment: How you do stretch a String vertically?

Comment: A Haskell `String` is a list of characters. It is not clear what you mean by "stretch"; adding some examples of the desired output might help. Furthermore, your pseudocode definition does not match its type signature.

Comment: If you have a list of strings representing the rows, and need to stretch the ANSI image x times wide and y times high, would you simply repeat the individual characters x times and repeat whole rows y times? Then shove the results together.

Comment: yes i believe that would work.

Comment: I have put together this but still cannot work out the bugs I'm almost there as I can get it to work if I import Pictures hiding (printPicture) but i don't want to do this I have `scaleX :: [Char] -> Int -> [Char]
    scaleX line n = foldl (++) "" [replicate n c | c<-line]
 
 scaleY :: Int -> Int -> IO()
    scaleY a n = concat [replicate n line | line<-a]
 
 scale :: Int -> Int -> IO()
    scale a n
      | n <= 0     = []
      | otherwise  = scaleY [scaleX line n | line<-a] n
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This answer is [literate Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Literate_programming). You can save it with a `.lhs` extension and load it in GHCi.**

To stretch a list of elements, we need to replicate each element and then stitch back the resulting list of lists into a single list. To do this, we map the `replicate` function over the elements and then stitch the resulting lists back together in a single step using `concatMap`:

```
> stretch :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
> stretch n = concatMap (replicate n)
```

NB: This could also be defined *pointfree* as

```
stretch = concatMap . replicate
```

Now we can stretch a grid (a list of lists) by stretching the rows and by mapping over the rows to stretch the elements inside them:

```
> expand :: Int -> Int -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
> expand n m = stretch n . map (stretch m)
```

*Can we reverse the order with the same result (`expand n m = map (stretch m) . stretch n`)? Why or why not?*

Now the only missing piece to make it work with your example is to convert back and forth between a string containing newlines and a list of strings split on newlines. `lines` and `unlines` will do this for us. (If your actual application involves grids rather than strings, you won't need to do this.)

```
> expansion :: Int -> Int -> String -> String
> expansion n m = unlines . expand n m . lines
```

*Why do we use `String` here when before we used `[a]`?*

Now to test it out:

```
λ> putStrLn $ expansion 2 2 "#.#\n..#"
##..##
##..##
....##
....##
```

Comment: I think you need parentheses around the final `stretch m` in the definition of `expand`. For me at least, with the code as-is, GHCi complains that `map` is applied to too many arguments.

Comment: @Mr.F Corrected. Thanks!

Comment: I did it `stretch n m = map (stretch1 n) . (stretch1 m)` but all works the same. Thanks @ReinHenrichs